# Constantly Loosing Session State ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, session

My site is constantly losing its session state and kicking users off and I can't figure out why.

I have an action filter that tries to check if the UserSession is still present, if not it checks if the user is authenticated and attempts to restore the user session based on the authenticated user id.

If the user isn't authenticated I then redirect them to the login page. I also have some code that checks if it's an ajax request and manually sets the statuscode to 403 so my ajax calls can identify this status and do the redirection within the javascript side.

**Here's my Action Filter:**

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            SecuredController baseController = filterContext.Controller as SecuredController;

            //  Check if the session is available
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserSession"] == null)
            {

                if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                    {
                        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
                        filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
                        {
                            Data = new { Error = "Unavailable", Url = "~/Account/Login" },
                            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                        };
                        return;
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl))
                    {
                        string returnUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login?returnUrl=" + returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login");
                    }
                }

                string userId = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId();

                Web.Helpers.Common common = new Helpers.Common();
                UserSession userSession = common.GetUserSession(userId);

                filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserSession"] = userSession;
            }

            //  Set the Current user to the session variable
            baseController.CurrentUser = (UserSession)filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserSession"];

            //  Continue executing the relevant action
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
```

**And here's my Javascript Code:**

```
$.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: rootUrl + serviceUrl,
            async: aSync,
            data: dataParameters,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                if (targetProgressContainer === undefined) {
                    return;
                }
                if ($(targetProgressContainer).length === 0) {
                    console.log('The Progress Container Div "' + targetProgressContainer + ' could not be found!');
                    return;
                }

                $(targetProgressContainer).html($(_progressContainer).html());
            },
            statusCode:{
                403: function (data) {
                    window.top.location.href = sessionEndedUrl;
                }
            },
            success: function (responseData, status, xhr) {
                    successCallback(responseData);
            },
            error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                errorCallback(request, textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

Here's my Startup.ConfigureAuth method:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            // Configure the sign in cookie
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                },

                SlidingExpiration =true,
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30)
            });
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
            app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

And some rules I added to ensure the user url is the full domain

```
 <rules>
        <rule name="Add www prefix to example.com domain" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Authentication session is expiring because authentication ticket has expired ?

Comment: Hey Hakunamatata, I added in the code for the authentication. Really don't understand why it's expiring.

Comment: Your logic looks OK. Only thing is default session timeout is 20 minutes so if there is no activity for 20 minutes your session will expire. Increase this value in config. Also IIS will recycle the app pool based on Idle Timeout value if there are no request to process. Increase this value as well.

Comment: It's so sporadic, there'll be periods of time where I'll be navigating the site just fine and suddenly it kicks me out. Other times I login and don't even get to navigate 2-3 pages and it kicks me out. I'm really at a loss here.

Comment: Could it be because of some bad server configuration? We had a similar experience at our workplace once and I'm pretty sure this problem was present in only one development server. If you have the luxury of checking it on another server, you could relieve yourself of some pain at least.

Comment: Your logic seems sound. 5 years ago I worked on (someone else's) ASP.NET site that also randomly expired sessions. As it didn't do it in Dev or UAT we ended up diagnosing the problem as a hardware fault - the production server had one faulty RAM chip. Replaced all the server's memory - problem went away. If I were you I'd try deploying the site to another environment and see if the problem persists,

Comment: The server process (app pool) could be recycling automatically (because of high CPU or memory consumption) and depending on how you store sessions (if they're not persistent but just in memory), this could lead to killing all sessions. Check errors in the event viewer.

Comment: @sh1rts - Unfortunately it's hosted at a popular asp.net provider so I can't diagnose any sort of hardware issue and I'm at pains to move this to another provider at this time as the system is live etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>In one of your comments you mentioned that the issue is intermittent - it works fine most of the time but sometimes the user gets "kicked out"?
At the risk of asking the obvious - do you use "in-proc" sessions and run your application on the web farm?</strike>

The symptoms you described would occur if your app runs behind a load balancer and it uses "in-proc" sessions. In such case the user will be fine as long as the load balancer directs the requests to the same server. If, later on, the load balancer decides to direct one of the requests to another server the user's session information wouldn't be available there and your code will send the redirect to the login page.

**UPDATE 1**

I focused on the session part but it seems like the problem is with the authentication cookie. In that case the cookie is encrypted/decrypted using keys specified in the **<machineKey>** part of your web.config. If those settings are different for different servers within the web farm then the auth cookie encrypted on one server cannot be decrypted on a different one causing the "IsAuthenticated" property of the user to be false. Do you have the  settings in your web.config as described here: [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx)?

**UPDATE 2** - how to add machine key to your web.config

Following a question in the comments below here's the easiest way to add the machine key to your application (example based on IIS7).

1. Go to your local IIS select your site and on the fetures pane double-click "Machine Key" icon.

[image]

If you don't have your application in the local IIS you can generate the keys on a "dummy" site and copy the configuration section to your app's web.config later.

2. Click "Generate Keys"

[image]

3. Check the site's web.config

[image]

4. Your keys will look like the example below

[image]

You can now simply copy the `<machineKey>` to your application web.config.

Comment: Hey Rafal, yes, it's in-proc and hosted on a popular asp.net hosting provider, so I assume it would be on a web farm. I thought though that when the session gets lost I could use the users authentication cookie (AspNet.ApplicationCookie) to reload the session, but this is getting lost as well. Does this mean that the AspNet.ApplicationCookie is also stored in session on the server?

Comment: So maybe it's about <machineKey> settings in the web.config? I've updated my answer.

Comment: Does this apply to me given that this is a single application

Comment: Yes it does. The moment you want to run your application in the load balanced environment you should add <machineKey> settings to your web.config. If you don't have this setting in you config then you will experience the kind of intermittent problems like the problem with decrypting the authentication cookie. Another think that will brake every now and again is ViewState if you use one. ViewState is also encrypted using the key from the <machineKey> section. For ViewState you'll get an exception "Invalid ViewState" as described here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2915218

Comment: I added in the machine key via IIS from a post I saw, Options: SHA Encryption Auto, Validation Key -> Generate a unique key and Decryption Key -> Generate a unique key. My site went down and I got this error "Decryption key specified has invalid hex characters." and I see it has 'isolateapps' in the keys. If i remove it IsolateApps it works. What's the diff.

Comment: The keys should consist only of hexadecimal characters. In my IIS7 I can only have values "AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" or the actual key. Not a mixture of key and "IsolateApps" - that would, as you described, cause an error. I added another update to my answer which explain how to get those keys. I hope it helps :-)

Comment: Thanks Rafal, it seems like that's exactly what the problem was. Very much appreciated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115498/discussion-between-rafal-zajac-and-webcognoscere).

Answer (score 1):

We encountered a similar problem in our application, and perhaps this will help you.  The authentication token is stored as a cookie, and our application was storing lots of other information in cookies as well, and the names of some of these cookies were dynamically generated.  We discovered that different browsers have limits to how many cookies they will store for a site, and will throw away the oldest unmodified cookies.  If you haven't refreshed your authentication cookie for a while, it eventually gets to be the oldest one, and gets thrown away.  For us, the solution was to move most places where we were using cookies over to local storage, keeping our list of cookies to a well-defined and limited list.